# How to split data from groupby into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I create new table from group by function as follow

| BIRTH_RATE | Credit | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (339.999, 566.0] | Bad | 9829 |
| (339.999, 566.0] | Good | 101495 |
| (566.0, 788.0] | Bad | 336 |
| (566.0, 788.0] | Good | 2345 |
| (788.0, 1011.0] | Bad | 1910 |
| (788.0, 1011.0] | Good | 24616 |

with code:

```
df[['BIRTH_RATE', 'Credit','ID']].groupby(by=['BIRTH_RATE','Credit']).count()
```

And I would like to split Credit row into columns

```sql
(Credit Total = Good + Bad)
(Bad rate = (Bad/Total)*100)
```

| BIRTH_RATE | Credit Total | Bad | Good | Bad rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (339.999, 566.0] | 111324 | 9829 | 101495 | 8.8 |
| (566.0, 788.0] | 2681 | 336 | 2345 | 12.5 |
| (788.0, 1011.0] | 26526 | 1910 | 24616 | 7.2 |

I have try to create Credit Total with the following code

```
df.groupby(["BIRTH_RATE"]).agg(Credit=('Credit', 'count'))
```

Comment: the best library to use for data manipulation in python is pandas. the community is huge and very easy to use. try it with pandas

Comment: You are looking for `df.pivot` from the looks of it.

Comment: @Corralien probably if he skips the groupby right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot` to reformat your dataframe and `assign` to create the two new columns:

```
out = df.pivot_table(values='ID', index='BIRTH_RATE', columns='Credit', aggfunc='sum') \
        .assign(**{'Credit Total': lambda x: x['Bad']+x['Good'],
                   'Bad Rate': lambda x: round(x['Bad']/(x['Bad']+x['Good'])*100, 1)}) \
        .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(out)

# Output:
         BIRTH_RATE   Bad    Good  Credit Total  Bad Rate
0  (339.999, 566.0]  9829  101495        111324       8.8
1    (566.0, 788.0]   336    2345          2681      12.5
2   (788.0, 1011.0]  1910   24616         26526       7.2
```

Comment: I got the error

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @mrsnoopy. I updated my solution. I replaced `pivot` by `pivot_table` and aggregate with `sum`

Comment: The error is raised because you have more than one row of same (BIRTH_RATE, Credit). You have to take a decision when you encounter, for example, 2 rows of  `(339.999, 566.0], Bad`

Comment: it's work! thank you. I have been stuck with this problem for hours.

Comment: @mrsnoopy. Take care, I chose to use `sum` but maybe you want to take the `mean` or `first` to take the first value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty straight forward way to do it.  Get your good/bad columns witha  simple pivot.  Then it's very easy to calculate the rest.

```
df = df.pivot(index='BIRTH_RATE',columns='Credit',values='ID').reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
df['Credit Total'] = df['Bad']+df['Good']
df['Bad Rate'] = (df['Bad']/df['Credit Total'])*100
print(df)
```

Output

```
         BIRTH_RATE   Bad    Good  Credit Total   Bad Rate
0  (339.999, 566.0]  9829  101495        111324   8.829183
1    (566.0, 788.0]   336    2345          2681  12.532637
2   (788.0, 1011.0]  1910   24616         26526   7.200483
```

Comment: I have tried with this code but I got the output as follow:
`
BIRTH_RATE   Bad    Good  Credit Total   Bad Rate
0  (339.999, 566.0] 8.570451e+09  8.570451e+09       1.714108e+10   49.999479
1    (566.0, 788.0]   8.570451e+09    8.570451e+09          1.714108e+10  50.000147
2   (788.0, 1011.0]  8.570451e+09   8.570451e+09         1.714108e+10  49.999728
`